# Account Field History Exceeding limit

Tags: account, limits, field-history

Did something change regarding standard object field history tracking?

I just refreshed my sandbox, I'm tracking less than **20 fields on Account** (currently 17). When I try to deploy account object using ANT, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: objects/Account.object(1122,13):exceeded the allowed number of fields to track on a given entity
```

Also, does the **Account Feed History** are included in the limit or is it a separated limit ?

Comment: deploy against PROD?  what is the # of tracked fields in PROD? any chance some of them are deleted but not erased?

Comment: Deploy sandbox to sandbox. I disabled Account Feed History and I still have the same issue

Comment: I've seen things similar to this in the (distant) past where the target org had fields defined as trackable in Set S and the source org was for fields in set T and where the union of sets S and T was greater than 20 members. I had to untrack some fields in the target org first